# Convert string to datetime python with milli-seconds

Tags: python, datetime

**Problem:** I have the following string `'2021-03-10T09:58:17.027323+00:00'` which I want to convert to datetime. I have difficulties with the format. This is what I tried so far:

```
datetime.strptime('2021-03-10T09:58:17.027323+00:00', "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.z")
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct format string is `"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z"`

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime('2021-03-10T09:58:17.027323+00:00', "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")
datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 10, 9, 58, 17, 27323, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
>>> datetime.fromisoformat('2021-03-10T09:58:17.027323+00:00')
datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 10, 9, 58, 17, 27323, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

But as mentioned in the comments - better use `fromisoformat()`

Answer (score 0):

Given that your string is known from before and you won't be using a now time feature, you can check [here](https://stackabuse.com/converting-strings-to-datetime-in-python/) I think you can use the following code:

```
   import datetime

   date_time_str = '2018-06-29 08:15:27.243860'
   date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
   
   print('Date:', date_time_obj.date())
   print('Time:', date_time_obj.time())
   print('Date-time:', date_time_obj)
```

Comment: this will be naive (timezone unaware) datetime object. OP has timezone info.